# Android spinning wheel (pizza)

Tags: android

I am trying to create a circle wheel divided in a fixed number of sections. Each section should be clickable.

How I approach this? Should I make an image and set as a background or is there a way to draw all parts in java?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly:

Create .png with pizza.

Create new widget, extending View.

Override `onDraw()` and draw it to canvas with some rotation. Optionally you can draw lines with java if it's margeritta not a pepperoni.

If necessary - change rotation call `invalidate()` to redraw view

Add `onTouch()` listener, get position ot tap, calculate what sector was touched.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution would be to draw different paths for each piece on a Canvas (path.lineTp and path.addCircle - think so). Then you can add ClickListeners to the paths and they will be clickable....